# Multiple search field elasticsearphp

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

Hello i want to do something like that with elasticsearch [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYyPL.png)

I already have some knowledge in elasticsearch but I can't understand how can I do this , multiple search

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`bool/must/should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) clause to combine multiple conditions

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "tag"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "answers": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "user": 1234
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "words here",
            "type": "phrase"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "score": 3
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "isaccepted": "yes"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you want to search on multiple fields then you can use [multi_match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html)

> If no fields are provided, the multi_match query defaults to the
> index.query.default_field index settings, which in turn defaults to *.
> This extracts all fields in the mapping that are eligible to term queries and filters the metadata fields. All extracted fields are then
> combined to build a query.

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "answers": 0,
  "isaccepted": "no"
}
{
  "answers": 0,
  "isaccepted": "yes"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "yes"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67542669",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "answers": 0,
          "isaccepted": "yes"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: if i have 3 fields to search in it  and sometimes user choose only 2 fields , sometimes search in only one field or both 3 fields i don't think this can work with what i want to do

Comment: @ameell if all the fields are not compulsory, then you can use `should` clause instead of `must`. `should` clause works the same as the logical OR operator. Please try this query with your sample index data, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Thank u for ur answer but I don't understand how it can be work because with sould also I must specifiy all the fields , if user choose for expl search in (age , content) or ( content , title , age , autor) and now in ( content , autor , age) ... what about fields that their value is null ? or I will create a function search for each case ? which is not possible

Comment: @ameell in this case you can use multi_match query --> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html, if no fields are specified in the `fields` param this query extracts all fields and searches for the query in all the fields. Even if one of the field have null value, it will not affect the search result

Comment: "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "Will Smith",
      "type":       "cross_fields",
      "fields":     [ "first_name", "last_name" ],
      "operator":   "and"
    }
   is executed as:

+(first_name:will last_name:will)
+(first_name:smith last_name:smith) with that I can't specify exact value in exact field for example search ( "alen" , "alex")  execution will ( author : "alen",name= "alex") or ( author : "alex",name= "alen") so the result will be not true if there is documet which have  ( author : "alex",name= "alen") they will return result but a wrong result

Comment: @ameell if you want to search the query field-wise (i.e `alex` should match `author` field and `alen` should match the `name` field), then you need to use the bool query as  given above in the answer. Have you tried the bool query shown above?

Comment: yes i already try it but that's not what I want to do

Comment: @ameell please provide some sample index data and expected search result so that I can provide a working example for the same